# JAXB giving an exception when trying to Marshall with given order

Tags: java, exception, jaxb

i have a code similar to this

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
@XmlType(propOrder={"param1", "param2""})
public class Demo{
public Demo() {
}
private int param1;
private String param2;
private String param3;



public int getparam1() {
    return param1;
}

@XmlElement
public void setparam1(int param1) {
    this.param1= param1;
}

//other setters and getters here except for param3
}
```

but it gives me

```
      n4 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
```

exception when i try to run the program (i have 6 parameters in total in original code and only 4 is use for Marshall )

What would be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in the @XmlType anntation:

```
@XmlType(propOrder={"param1", "param2","param3"})
```

If this not fix the problem, try to check the name of the properties in the propOrder OR directly use field accessor type:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(propOrder={"param1", "param2", "param3"})
public class Demo{

public Demo() {
}

private int param1;
private String param2;
private String param3;

//getter & setters without annotations

}
```

Comment: yes but i want to only take 2 parameters out of 3 in my program in XML.so giving @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) would make all of them appear on the xml right?

Comment: @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE), then @XmlElement only on the fields you want as output.